# JBPM - Get the list of all the tasks

Tags: java, task, jbpm

I'm trying to fetch the list of all the tasks within the JBPM database. I'm using the following code :

```
 List<Task> liste = taskService.createTaskQuery().list();
```

But it gives me a list of the first task of each workflow... How could I get the other tasks?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve all task instances

```
    JbpmConfiguration conf = JbpmConfiguration.parseResource("jbpm.cfg.xml");
    JbpmContext context = conf.createJbpmContext();
    List<TaskInstance> taskList = context.getTaskList();
```

To retrieve task instances using actor

```
    JbpmConfiguration conf = JbpmConfiguration.parseResource("jbpm.cfg.xml");
    JbpmContext context = conf.createJbpmContext();
    List<TaskInstance> taskList = context.getTaskList("Head of Department");
```

Comment: sorry, here what is jbpm.cfg.xml?